# MySQL query question: Reservation Like System

Tags: mysql

Have rooms that may or may not have reservations. Reservations are from(date) to till(date). Person searches for rooms by date: from_field and till_field. Trying to find if a room is available.

```
SELECT rooms.* FROM rooms
LEFT JOIN reservations ON reservations.room_id = rooms.id
WHERE ( reservations.from > till_field OR reservations.till < from_field )
```

PROBLEM: If a single reservation succeeds it seems that the query has the room as available, even though another reservation occupies the spot.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is causing problems, when there aren't any reservations it won't return the room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***How to retrieve rooms with no resevations at all:***

In case there is no reservations, there will be no `reservations` row returned by the query => you have to check for that also (`reservations.room_id IS NULL`):

```
SELECT rooms.* FROM rooms
LEFT JOIN reservations ON reservations.room_id = rooms.id
WHERE reservations.room_id IS NULL -- if there is no reservations
      OR reservations.from > till_field
      OR reservations.till < from_field
```

***But to actually get what ou want, you have to check for rooms that don't have any reservation with:***

<sub>`fromDate or tillDate between from_field and till_field`</sub>

OR
`fromDate < from_field and tillDate > till_field`

```
SELECT rooms.*
  FROM rooms
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM reservations 
                  WHERE reservations.room_id = rooms.id
                    AND ((
                          reservations.from BETWEEN from_field AND till_field
                          OR
                          reservations.till BETWEEN from_field AND till_field
                         )
                        OR
                         (
                          reservations.from < from_field
                          AND reservations.till > till_field
                         )
                        )
                  )
```

Comment: Problem... if a single reservation succeeds the query says the room is available. Is there a way to have ALL the left joined reservations succeed for the room to be available?

Comment: Thanks, haven't got it working yet. The real query is a lot more complicated but this will help a bunch.